# How do I switch selection method

Tags: selection-tools

How do I switch from (for example) select Lasso to Select Box?

I've tried searching up how but I only get tutorials from pre blender 2.8

Comment: you can always ctrl + LMB to lasso select and B to box select

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the default Blender Keymap you can cycle the active selection tool with the <kbd>W</kbd> key by default, between *Tweak Tool*, *Select Box*, *Select Circle* and *Select Lasso*.

[image]

Comment: for left click select that is.

Comment: You can also long press on the cursor icon on the top left to have all the options without the need to circle between all of them